# How can I calculate the maximum and minimum of this function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

[image]

This is incorrect and I have a feeling I am not doing this correctly.

Comment: Use $$y=\pm\sqrt{5-9x^2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your unease. The origin is a saddle point, as the Hessian can say:

$$H(0,0) = \begin{vmatrix} f_{xx} (0,0) & f_{xy} (0,0) \\ f_{xy} (0,0) & f_{yy} (0,0) \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{vmatrix} = -1.$$

As for nonzero points, I have continued from your system the following way: we can write

$$\lambda = \frac{x}{2y} \text{ and } \lambda = \frac{y}{18x},$$

therefore

$$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{y}{9x} \text{ and } 9x^2 =y^2, \text{ hence } 3x = \pm \, y.$$

Using this on the restriction $9x^2 +y^2 = 5$ yields

$$9x^2 + 9x^2 = 18x^2 = 5 \text{ and } x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3 \sqrt{2}}.$$

In total we have four points:

$$
\begin{align}
(x_1, y_1) & = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \frac{1}{3}, 1 \right), \\
(x_2, y_2) & = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \frac{1}{3}, -1 \right), \\
(x_3, y_3) & = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}} \left( -\frac{1}{3}, -1 \right), \\
(x_4, y_4) & = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}} \left( -\frac{1}{3}, 1 \right).
\end{align}
$$

For them find

$$f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_3,y_3) = \frac{5}{6} \text{ and } f(x_2,y_2) = f(x_4,y_4) = - \frac{5}{6},$$

as respectively maximum and minimum.

Comment: How did you get the four points? for the y points. How did you get 1 and -1

Comment: From the equations $3x= \pm \, y$ and $x = \pm \sqrt{5}/( 3 \sqrt{2})$. I found values for $x$ in the second and corresponding values for $y$ in the first.

Comment: In the same vein as my remark in your linear function and constraint ellipse problem elsewhere, here we have a function with "diagonal symmetry" ( $ \ f(x,y) \ = \ xy \ $ ) and a constraint curve with four-fold symmetry.  This produces maxima and minima pairs, each arranged on lines through the center of the curve and symmetrical about lines parallel to the coordinate axes (the curve need not be centered on the origin).